# How to play 4K/UHD videos

Tags: video, gpu-driver

On this machine, an Acer Aspire E5 laptop computer, I have a dual booth with Ubuntu Studio 16.04 and Windows 10.

On Windows 10, 4K and UHD videos work perfectly.

On Ubuntu they basically don't work. As soon as the file opens, audio works fine but the video is loaded at a framerate of more or less one frame every three seconds.

To check this I used an MP4 video.

Is there a package I need to install to optimize 4K/UHD videos?

Comment: What program are you using? I use VLC and it runs HD videos fine. @il mietitore

Comment: don't run them in the browser but some good video viewer like VLC or mpv

Comment: I use VLC and Totem. 4K videos on youtube work perfectly.